# Replacement for PhotoChooserTask in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Windows 8 app and would like to prompt the user to provide an image.

With Windows Phone I would have used a PhotoChooserTask, specified the required Pixel Height and Width, and that the camera was an acceptable input method.

I've found with Windows 8 I need to use either a CameraCaptureUI or FileOpenPicker to give the user similar options. I also need to manually process the resulting image to the required dimensions with the FileOpenPicker. The CameraCaptureUI has a cropping control built in.

Is there a library or control I could use that will give similar functionality to the Windows Phone PhotoChooserTask? Or can I access the cropping control portion of the CameraCaptureUI?

Specifically, I'd like prompt the user for an image of particular dimensions. They can then choose the image from either a file or capture a new one via a camera. Once they have the image they are presented with a UI to crop it to my required dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

CameraCaptureUI is the right way to go. You can specify properties for the Photo capture, as explained in this documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.photosettings

It will provide the user a nice interface to take a picture and crop/resize it, as it does in Windows Phone !

```
// Takes a photo with specified settings.
function takePhoto() {
    var captureUI = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
    captureUI.photoSettings.allowCropping = true;
    captureUI.photoSettings.croppedAspectRatio.height = 3;
    captureUI.photoSettings.croppedAspectRatio.width = 4;
    captureUI.photoSettings.croppedSizeInPixels.height = 0;
    captureUI.photoSettings.croppedSizeInPixels.width = 0;
    captureUI.photoSettings.format = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.jpeg;
    captureUI.photoSettings.maxResolution = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.highestAvailable;
    captureUI.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).then(function (capturedItem) {
        if (capturedItem) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "User captured a photo."
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "User didn't capture a photo."
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this part works well. But Windows phone provides one class that will allow the user to make the choice between the camera and a file as the source of the image. After that they are given a consistent UI to crop if required.

Comment: Mmh ok, when I first read your question I thought the question was about cropping more than unified solution. Now, looking at the other applications (and even the way you can change your profile picture in the Windows 8 settings), there are always two options in the Bottom App Bar : "pick a file" or "take a picture". So I'm afraid you will have to build your own unified solution to allow cropping after the user has chosen a photo either from the camera or somewhere else.

Comment: I suspect you are correct and there isn't a cropping control available out of the box. Its a shame they didn't split the control out of the CameraCaptureUI for usage elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the user a single button to pick from and then allow them to choose either camera, or existing using a Menu like the one found in Calisto. Or you can offer them two buttons. With Windows 8 you have a little more real estate then you do on the phone.

To go directly to pictures, you can set the [SuggestedStartLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of the FileOpenPicker. This property accepts a [PickerLoctionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid.aspx). You should set this to `PickerLoctionId.PicturesLibrary`

Comment: This is roughly what I've ended up it. The only annoying part is that I'll have to create my own cropping control to handle the output of the FileOpenPicker.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that there is not much out there to offer cropping functionality on either the phone or windows 8. I did find [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bd9d1a0c-6722-4527-aeed-65e59f77f3f3), which might help you.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that post a used it to crop the FileOpenPicker images to the required dimensions. It may be I need to build out a UI to give control of the cropping. I also found various suggestions of a [CropControl for WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/437213).